# Python, Socketing between Windows and Raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, windows, sockets, unix, raspberry-pi3

so ive just started leaning about socketing when I came across an odd problem. I can make a connection between my Window computer and my Raspberry pi when the Pi is running my server script and my Windows running my client script, but when I try to run the server script on my Windows and client on my Pi they do not connect (after switching the host of course). Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
#server code
import socket
import time

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

host = '192.168.0.23'
port = 2613

serversocket.bind((host, port))
serversocket.listen(5)
while True:
    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    currentTime = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(currentTime.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

and

```
#client code
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.0.23'
port = 2613

clientserver.connect((host,port))
print s.recv(1024)
clientserver.close
```

Comment: 1- this code will not work on same machine, 2- Server can't talk first(if not a broadcasting server), 3- Define a timeout  period, 4- Connection succesfull is a message(sendin null or informatic data does'nt  matter), 5- Need use four port for speed-up data rate !, 6- Single data operations required a external function without loop. 7- Server using TCP methods but how ro resolve methods on clients side(use `socket.create_connection`)

Comment: Windows firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client code you have a  clientsocket which you then call clientserver then call s. Both clientserver and s are undefined. Try:

```
#client code
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.0.23'
port = 2613

clientsocket.connect((host,port))
print (clientsocket.recv(1024))
clientsocket.close
```

Also try running the server script on Windows with Administrator privileges so it can open the port and check your firewall settings on Windows for port 2613.

Comment: Shoot, it was just the firewall. Thank you!